# Ruby How to call module methods from class in the same namespace

Tags: ruby, mixins

I am new to Ruby and trying to understand the module methods in ruby.

```
module M1
    def comments 
      if @comments
        @comments
      else
        @comments = []
      end
    end

    def add_comment(comment)
       comments << comment
    end

    class Audio

         <<How do i call add_comment or comments >>
         def someMethod
            add_comment "calling module method from class which is in  same namespace or module"
         end

    end

end
```

Getting the following exception if I call on Module or Class. 
(undefined method `add_comment' for M1:Module)

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can declare a class method with `self.add_comment` and then call it from your instance as `M1.add_comment`.

Comment: Modules may contain two kinds of methods: module methods and instance methods. The former are defined on a module `M` as `def M.mm...end` or more commonly, `def self.mm...end` from within the module. These are invoked on the module (e.g. `Math.sqrt(10)`). Instance methods--what you have in your example--require an instance of a class `C` as their receiver and therefore must be instance methods of `C`. The latter can only be achieved by executing `C.include M` or `include M` from within `C` (or from an ancestor of `C`). If `M` is included in `C` any module methods in `M` are passed over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can cover this off with a *lazy initializer*:

```
def comments 
  @comments ||= [ ]
end
```

Where that populates `@comments` with an empty array unless it's already defined.

That makes the `add_comment` method redundant since you can just do:

```
comments << comment
```

Without any intermediation.

Now note that the `comments` method is defined as a *mixin method*, not as a stand-alone one. That means it doesn't exist until some other module or class calls `include` on that module.

To make it stand-alone:

```
def self.comments 
  @comments ||= [ ]
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
M1.comments << 'New comment'
```